# Warp array of vertices (polygon) according to the bounding box

Tags: objective-c, matrix, geometry, polygon, affinetransform

I'm working in Objective-C, and storing my vertices points in an NSArray.

I have an array of 2D vertices with their bounding box, which I call "polygon".

I would like to distort the whole polygon according to how I move the corners points of the bounding box. 
I guess I'll have to calculate some proportions depending on which corner I'm dragging. But, I don't know from where to begin for the calculations, and if there's a simple and fast algorithm for this. I don't want to use an external library, adn perform the calculations directly in my program.

The image here is produced by using an image software "distort" function, that does exactly what I want. If it is possible on a bitmap image, I suppose it is possible on any matrix of points.

[image: Distort]

Comment: Probably, you need some kind of affine transformation (but clarification of question is needed)

Comment: Sorry, the question still is not clear for me